# Decompile ICS app and Recompile on Gingerbread

Tags: android, compilation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is it possible to decompile a Ice Cream Sandwhich app (which I got off of the ICS emulater) and recompile it to run on Gingerbread? I got it to decompile then opened it in eclipse and tried to run it on my android 2.2 device but it just crashes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to decompile an android app.  However, if the app is using APIs that are not available on gingerbread, you will need to rewrite those portions of the code so that it can run on gingerbread.

Comment: I was using apktool to decompile it, But I guess it was using newer APIs, anyways thanks!

Comment: Yup.  Decompiling an app, and making the app use a different API are two completely different problems.  Good luck though.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to decompile then recompile the ICS launcher but it was having issues decompiling.